# Failed to get dependency from git on git post-update hook

Tags: git, go, githooks

I have a golang project and i want to build it on server as I push it

post-update hook is fired, everything nice, project is checked out to some directory, but, after it attempts to get dependency (`cd /go/src/kiyanov.com/app/` and `go get` ) it fails with an error

`remote # cd /go/src/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go; git show-ref
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: package github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go: exit status 128`

`remote # cd /go/src/github.com/lib/pq; git show-ref
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: package github.com/lib/pq: exit status 128`

`remote: # cd /go/src/golang.org/x/oauth2; git show-ref
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: package golang.org/x/oauth2: exit status 128`

gopath is exported properly, and packages are downloaded. 
but go install following after this commands are failed

go install works fine after the following push, once post-update make everything again in existing directory.

I don't have any ideas why it not works .The only suggestion cause it happens inside post-update hook, but i'm not sure.

Comment: I find out the source of problem why go install didn't work
one of golang packages wasn't installed ( cause of git issues ? I don't know ) 

the package was: `"golang.org/x/net/context"` and i guess it was a dependency for `"golang.org/x/oauth2"`

After I add that package to my go, it make go install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to install Jenkins, move all scripts to it, and initiate building with Jenkins from `post-update` script